# Docker hybrid swarm mesh routing not workingwindows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm

- Windows Version: Server 2019
- Docker for Windows Version: 18.09.0
- Linux Version: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Linux Node Docker Version: 18.09.0

Issue: Ingress routing between nodes in hybrid (linux/windows) swarm is not working as intended

Overview: Two docker nodes running the same release. Both server nodes exist on the same network subnet. Linux node is acting as swarm manager, the swarm was initialized with the `docker swarm init` command and the Windows node was joined using the token command that was generated.

Example of issue: For a visualizer I have deployed swarmpit to the swarm using two commands (per their site):

```
git clone https://github.com/swarmpit/swarmpit -b 1.5.1
docker stack deploy -c swarmpit/docker-compose.yml swarmpit
```

I am able to access the swarmpit UI on the linux node at `10.10.16.61:888` (internal port `8080` exposed in the above stack file)

With the ingress mesh, I should also be able to access the UI on the Windows node at `10.10.16.60:888`, however I am not.

Let me know if I can provide any more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/admin/configure/join-windows-worker-nodes/#install-ucp

> The swarm mode routing mesh can’t be used on Windows nodes. You can expose a port for your service in the host where it is running, and use the HTTP routing mesh to make your service accessible using a domain name.